# Continuous image of a path connected set is path connected.

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X \Rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function. Where $X$ is path connected .For $f(x),f(y) \in Y$  as$x,y\in X$ and if P be the path between $x $ and $ y$  then  $f \dot P$ is the path between $f(x),f(y) \in Y$.

Am I wrong?

Comment: By $f\dot{P}$, do you mean the composition $f\circ P$?

Comment: Yes . Actually I don't know how to write this composition sign. Please help.

Comment: It's just \circ

Answer (score 2):

You're right, but you need to be careful here! The space $f(X)$ is path connected, but the space $Y$ isn't in general unless $f$ is a surjection.

To see that $f(X)$ is path connected. Let $x,y \in f(X)$, then there exists $a,b \in X$ such that $f(a)=x$ and $f(b)=y$. Since $X$ is path connected, there exists a path $\gamma : [0,1] \to X$ such that $\gamma(0)=a$ and $\gamma(1)=b$.

Then $f\circ \gamma : [0,1] \to f(X)$ is such that $f\circ \gamma(0)=f(a)=x$ and $f\circ \gamma(1)=f(b)=y$. Hence $f\circ \gamma$ is a path from $x$ to $y$ as required.

Comment: Yes ..For image it is fine but for codomain subjectiveness is necessary.